# Can I use wildcards in GCP role definitions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use wildcard-permissions like `compute.*.get`, and `compute.*.list` in GCP IAM role definitions. Is it possible? If not I will file a feature request.

I just had the case in which I assigned 129 permissions to an GCP IAM role manually (without wildcard). This makes the intent of the role definition exceptionally hard to grasp. And I know I can do wildcard-permission management with Azure and AWS.

EDIT:

I created a feature request for it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159832667

Comment: My guess is that you have to specify all the permissions in a custom Role.  I do notice that you can create a custom role starting from an existing role which means that the existing permissions are copied ... from there you can add or subtract.

In your example, you said compute.instances.*.get .... this confuses me ... I always think of permissions as only made up of three elements ... so compute.instances.* makes sense but not compute.instances.*.get ... what would the wildcard match in that example?

Comment: @Kolban Thanks for the info. Actually I haven't noticed that it is only three elements. But you are right. I corrected my question.