# Adding apikeys.keys.getKeyString (alpha) permission to custom IAM role in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-key, google-iam

I have been trying to create a custom IAM role attached with the permission  apikeys.keys.getKeyString which is in alpha stage. I am not able to see this permission listed under the options to add it to the custom role.

This is the error I am getting when running a script -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.services.api-keys.get-key-string) PERMISSION_DENIED:  Permission 'apikeys.keys.getKeyString' denied on resource 'xxxxxxxxx'
```

However, when attaching the predefined role - API Keys Viewer, I am able to successfully run my script without an error. I assume that the permission apikeys.keys.getKeyString is added to the predefined role by default. Is there any way I can have this permission added to my custom role? Alternatively, is there another way I can get the API Key string using a standard permission instead of an alpha stage permission?

Comment: I do not know for this question, but some **alpha** features require your project being **whitelisted* by Google. This means you must request access to restricted features. To be able to request alpha access you need to join and be approved for **Google Insiders**. Contact your Google Cloud account representative for more details.

Answer (score 1):

According to the current [Understanding Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#earth-engine-roles), the predefined role, API Keys Viewer includes just:

- apikeys.keys.get,
- apikeys.keys.list,
- apikeys.keys.lookup.

You could try adding those permissions to your custom role to see if it works.

If not, you can make your [custom role based on an existing role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563927/can-i-use-wildcards-in-gcp-role-definitions) that does work, then add and remove any permissions you wish to change.

When the feature comes out of alpha, there may be other options.